# In SQL Server how can I fetch all rows with a date greater than some set date or at least 20 rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a way to fetch at least 20 rows, regardless of the date or all rows with a date greater than a set date (whichever of the 2 fetches the most rows).

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE the_date >= '2014-11-01'
ORDER BY the_date DESC
```

will give me what I want, but if this returns less than 20 rows then I want to keep going before that date until I get 20 (or until there are no more rows - whichever comes first).

I could just select all and take the ones I need programatically, but I'm trying to avoid that as that would be a major change to the actual code in many places.

Can this be done?

**Note:** I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You can select the first 20 rows, and then UNION that with a query that selects based on the date.

Comment: tried that - I need an example - can't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
select *
from
(
    select row_number() over (order by the_date desc) num, t.*
    from table1 t
) i
where i.the_date >= '2014-11-01'
or i.num < 21
```

Comment: Brilliant - even deals with duplicate dates - thank you

Answer (score 0):

Very strange requirement but something like this should work.

```
DECLARE @Date date = '2014-11-01';

with MyResults as
(
    SELECT *, 1 as RowNum
    FROM table1
    WHERE (the_date >= @Date )    

    UNION ALL

    SELECT top 10 *, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by the_date desc)
    FROM table1
    order by the_date desc
)

Select *
from MyResults
where RowNum <= 20
```

Comment: Yes, it is strange, but that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

The right answer was almost there, but the user has removed it, so here it is again:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE the_date >= '2014-11-01'
union
SELECT top 20 *
FROM table1
ORDER BY the_date desc
```

The removed answer had union all

This answer has a problem with duplicate dates , but with the data I have that is not an issue

Comment: If you don't have an issue with duplicate dates then put the union all back. The code you posted here will remove duplicates. You should also add an outer select to be explicit that the order by is on your top query.

Comment: That doesn't explain what happened. Do you understand the difference between union and union all. When you include all the query will not exclude duplicates, which is similar to a distinct. You state you don't have duplicate dates so using all would increase performance. But if the query works for you that is most important part.

Comment: it didn't work because it fetched more than 20 rows when it should not have, but Jace's answer covers it all